# Execute shell script in docker container with node

Tags: node.js, shell, docker

I'm trying to shell into a php container then run a command with node. I have tried using child_process.exec() but i'm not getting any errors or output back. Please let me know if there is something else I can try.  The shell script can take a long time (2 mins to 30 mins) to run so I want to also make sure it doesn't close before its done executing.

```
const { exec, spawn, } = require('child_process');
const openShell = spawn('docker-compose exec api bash;');

openShell.on('data', (data) => {
exec('shellscript.sh');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use stdout.on('data')?

```
const { exec, spawn, } = require('child_process');
const openShell = spawn('docker-compose exec api bash;');

openShell.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
exec('shellscript.sh');
});
```

There's various events for the process, stdout, and stderr, and your process may or may not use them.